# Display Product Options in Magento Order Report

Tags: magento, report

I'm making a custom report for Magento orders and I want to be able to sort the order listing by product options. Let's say the product option is `Postal` I'd like to be able to sort by that and see it in the Grid.

The product_options field is serialized and I cannot figure out for the life of me how to unserialize it and make it useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Loading the order item should give unserialised access to the product options attribute,

```
$orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->load($orderItemId);
$productOptions = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
```

Comment: That makes sense I guess I'm trying to understand how to place that into a custom report

Comment: for that you would need to extend /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php and add a new column to the grid, where it displays the $productOptions['Postal'] value for each item. Following article should help you in the right direction [link](https://www.atwix.com/magento/customize-orders-grid/)